# Verilog - "timescale"

Tags: syntax, verilog, fpga, vivado

**Question:**

I use "timescale" before module to regulate time, but Vivado tell me there is a syntax error at the first row. Please tell me the reason and what should I write?

**Display from Vivado:**

Error:Syntax Error near "".

**Code:**

```
'timescale 1ns/1ns
module datactl (data,in,data_ena);

    output [7:0] data;
    input [7:0] in;
    input data_ena;

    assign data = data_ena?in:8'bzzzz_zzzz;

endmodule
```

Comment: in addition to @dave_59 answer ,you don't need to use `8'bzzzz_zzzz` instead `8'bz` will work for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used a single quote `'` instead of a backtick `` ` ``. A compiler directives use a backtick. Note that there's no need for the `` `timescale `` directive unless your code has #delays or specify blocks.